# How to update android notifications in real time?

Tags: android

I have seen some applications update their notification content in real time. One example is the count down timer application.

[image]

Clicking on the `+ ADD 1 MIN` button immediately changes the notification text without any delay. How is this done? Or in other words how can I update the notifications in real time when the user clicks a button?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I typically declare a `NotificationCompat.Builder` as a member variable.

Then you can use that builder to update the Notification in the future.

```
private NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = null;

public void refreshNotifications() {
    if(mBuilder == null) {
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(false);
        mBuilder.setOngoing(true);
        mBuilder.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
        mBuilder.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_notification_outline);
        mBuilder.setOngoing(true);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.downloading_file));
    }

    mBuilder.setContentText(context.getString(R.string.total_progress, percentProgress));
    notificationManager.notify(DOWNLOADING_FILE, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: Key line is `mBuilder.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);` else you will get a lot of notifications.

Answer (score 1):

have you looked at this? from android docs...

```
mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
int notifyID = 1;
mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("New Message")
    .setContentText("You've received new messages.")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_status)
numMessages = 0;
// Start of a loop that processes data and then notifies the user
...
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentText(currentText)
        .setNumber(++numMessages);
    // Because the ID remains unchanged, the existing notification is
    // updated.
    mNotificationManager.notify(
            notifyID,
            mNotifyBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

To test, i did a countdown timer to update Notification

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000)
    {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            refreshNotifications("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish()
        {
        }
    }.start();
```

And update notification method like @Assaf told before

```
public void refreshNotifications(String message) {
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
    int notifyID = 1;
    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("New Message")
            .setContentText("You've received new messages.")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    int numMessages = 0;
    // Start of a loop that processes data and then notifies the user
    mBuilder.setContentText(message)
            .setNumber(++numMessages);
    // Because the ID remains unchanged, the existing notification is
    // updated.
    mNotificationManager.notify(
            notifyID,
            mBuilder.build());
}
```

And to do a custom layout you could read this documentation http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomNotification

Answer (score -1):

Set a timer in the text view. Whenever the "+ ADD 1 min" is pressed. update the timer with old timer + 1 Min.